Customizing The OAuthTokenIntrospectionEndPointFilter in Spring Security OAuth2 Authorization Server So I Can Add Logic to The Response
I'm using the Opaque token option to grant access to my clients in my Springboot OAuth2 Authorization Server. I'm aware of the fact that the resource server should verify the tokens using the token introspection end point. However, I'm adding some additional metadata to the Opaque token's claims like the authorities assigned to the particular user who granted the access, and even the particular endpoints that the user can have access to. I'm successfully able to inject this information to the token using OAuth2TokenCustomizer but I fail to find out where I can define the logic I want to use when the resource server reaches to the "introspect" end point so I can decide on The token being active/valid/ or whatever based on the claims I inserted into the token when Generating It and the additional parameters that the resource server will be providing in its request
I thought of having a custom Authentication provider for the introspection requests, but I feel like there has to be a clean way of doing it without having to override all the logic that's already exists and is needed
